# How to use Visual C++ (Windows) to get file/folder moved from where?

Tags: visual-c++

I would like to know, if i monitoring a directory(C:\test), how to use Visual C++ (Windows) to get a new file or folder that actually is moved from where(file/folder native/previous path), if there are any file/folder been moved into this directory (C:\test)?
  Thank you.

Regards,

Gordon

Answer (score 0):

I think that directory change notifications are what you're after (your question is not 100% clear to me) - have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365261(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I don't think so.  He seems to want to know which file was moved, and where from, which information might be available from the NTFS journal but the change notifications don't tell you much at all.